# How to log into website using windows account?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a button to the login of an internal website that will log the user in using their windows account.

So far I have tried setting the authentication mode to windows.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

and then getting the user name with

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

This works but it has a login pop up that I don't want to have
[Image of Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZonk.png).
Is there a way to not have the popup show since I don't want them to have to log in at all but still get their windows username?

Comment: what browser is that?  and are you logged into a windows domain or just your local PC?

Comment: The popup image is from chrome every browser has a different pop up. This would be logged into a windows domain.

Comment: In my experience you often see that dialog if you don't put the fully qualified domain name in your URL (e.g. you are making a request to `http://yourserver/yourapp` instead of `http://yourserver.yourdomain.org/yourapp`. Can't remember if it depends on use of HTTPS as well.

Comment: the pop up I think is supposed to show up since it is the windows authentication login. I am wondering if there is a way I can skip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We learned that the reason the sign in pop up was showing up was because the site was not set in the Local Intranet Zone. We added the site to that and it works as intended.